# Creating and Checking cookies value with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm setting up a new pop up and would like to create cookie. The basic function is to add classes into the wrapper if a cookie exists (or depending on value if that's possible). This is what I got so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="new-popup" class="active ">
<span class="collapse-popup">X</span>
<form>
<input class="tnp-email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="ne" required="">
<input class="tnp-submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

JS/JQUERY:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var popuptwo = $('#new-popup');
    var cookie = GetCookie("testbb2020");
    if(cookie == null) { }

    if(cookie === 'closed') { 
        $('#new-popup').addClass('closed-test')
    }

    if(cookie === 'subscribed') { 
        $('#new-popup').addClass('subscribed-test')
    }

    // Click on "Close"
    $('#new-popup .collapse-popup').click(function(event) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = "testbb2020=closed" + expires + "; path=/"; {
        }

    });

    // Click on "Subscribe"
    $('#new-popup input.tnp-submit').click(function(event) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = "testbb2020=subscribed" + expires + "; path=/"; {
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery no longer has an active plugin for this. Two alternatives exist depending on your needs:

- you can use [JS-Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for a way to work with cookies in Javascript
- you can use [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead of cookies

LocalStorage is the easier way, but if you need compatibility with older browsers go with cookies.